# PHP abs negative number

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to do a date compare with an If statement.

It works fine to tell me that YES the date is before today however it will not give me a negative number to NO the date is after today.

Here is what i have.

```
$datetime= date('Y-m-d');
$time=strtotime($datetime);
echo "<br><br>Today is " . $datetime;
$datetime1= $row['edate'];
$time1=strtotime($datetime1);
echo "<br>The date to compare is " . $row['date'];
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM table where name='" . $row['name']. "'");
$row3 = mysql_fetch_row($result3);
$start = $time;
$end = strtotime($row3[0]);
$between = ceil(abs($end - $start) / 86400);
```

This will output the correct values for TODAY'S date and the END DATE

Let say today is 2014-09-09 and our end date is 2014-09-12

```
echo "<br>There are<b> ". $between. "</b> days left";
```

OUTPUT: There are 3 days left

Now if i get a different date say 2014-09-06
I get the same output.

```
echo "<br>There are<b> ". $between. "</b> days left";
```

OUTPUT: There are 3 days left

I want to see:

There are -3 days left

I want to put this all in an if statement to display a record form the database.

```
if ($between < 0){
DONT SHOW RECORD
}
else {
SHOW RECORD
}
```

Problem is $between is never less than 0

Simple test

```
$t = 10;
$o = 12;
$difference = abs($o-$t);
echo "The Difference is ".$difference;
```

OUTPUT: Difference is 2

```
$t = 10;
$o = 12;
$difference = abs($t-$o);
echo "The Difference is ".$difference;
```

OUTPUT: Difference is 2

Why not Difference is -2

Comment: You do realise what the [abs()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) function does, don't you?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question but you seem to have abs function when calculating $between and $difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ABS()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) function in PHP takes the absolute value which is the positive value of whatever you put in. `ABS(10-12)=2` and `ABS(12-10)=2`. It seems like you just want distance between them in which you can use

```
$difference = $t-$o;
```

Comment: Or you could just remove `abs()` and get the actual value.

Comment: Ah you're right, i thought he _always_ wanted the negative absolute value

Answer (score 2):

abs() gives u absolute number, which means that it could never be negative. Change abs() to intval() or cast it to int ( c-style)

```
$difference = (int)$t - (int)$o;
```

As a side-note: You should escape your sql queries and you could achieve the same result with only using a sql query. There is no need for date comparison on php side with this kind of simple solution.